# How to create a view which merges two tables?

Tags: sql, view

I have two tables which have the exact same structure. Both tables can store the same data with different primary keys (autoincremented integers). Therefore, there is a third table which lists which two primary keys list the same data. However, there also exist rows which don't exist in the other. Therefore, a simple join won't work since you will have two rows with the same primary key but different data. Therefore, is there a way of reassigning primary keys to unused values in the view?

### Table1

```
 ID    name
 1     Adam
 2     Mark
 3     David
 4     Jeremy
```

### Table2

```
 ID    name
 1     Jessica
 2     Jeremy
 3     David
 4     Mark
```

### Table3

```
 T1ID  T2ID
 2     4
 3     3
 4     2
```

I am looking for a result table like the following:

### Result

```
 ID    name
 1     Adam
 2     Mark
 3     David
 4     Jeremy
 5     Jessica
```

The real heart of the question is how i can assign the temporary fake id of 5 to Jessica and not just some random number. The rule I want for the ids is that if the row exists in the first table, then use its own id. Otherwise, use the next id that an insert statement would have generated (the column is on autoincrement).

Comment: It will be more clear if you can provide sample data and expected result in your question

Comment: In addition to the comment by Anil, it would perhaps help if you told as what exactly you try to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer to edited question

```
select id, name from table1
union all
select X.offset + row_number() over (order by id), name
from (select MAX(id) offset from table1) X
cross join table2
where not exists (select * from table3 where t2id = table2.id)
```

The MAX(id) is used to "predict" the next identity that would occur if you merged the data from the 2nd table into the first.  If Table3.T2ID exists at all, it means that it is already included in table1.

Using the test data below

```
create table table1 (id int identity, name varchar(10))
insert table1 select 'Adam' union all
select 'Mark' union all
select 'David' union all
select 'Jeremy'

create table table2 (id int identity, name varchar(10))
insert table2 select 'Jessica' union all
select 'Jeremy' union all
select 'David' union all
select 'Mark'

create table table3 (t1id int, t2id int)
insert table3 select 2,4 union all
select 3,3 union all
select 4,2
```

---

#### Answer to original question below

So the 3rd table is the one you want to build (a view instead of a table)?

```
select newid=row_number() over (order by pk_id), *
from
(
    select a.*
    from tblfirst a
    UNION ALL
    select b.*
    from tblsecond b
) X
```

The data will contain a unique `newid` value for each record, whether from first or second table.  Change `pk_id` to your primary key column name.

Comment: this seems right, last question though, is there no better way to determine the next insert id than just asking for the max?

Comment: @cha There is `dbcc checkident` but it is not always accurate (if table was empty) and it certainly cannot be used as part of a select statement

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, following might work

1. Select everything from your first table
2. Select everything from your second table that is not linked to your third table
3. Combine the results

**Test data**

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1, 1), Value VARCHAR(32))
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1, 1), Value VARCHAR(32))
DECLARE @Table3 TABLE (T1ID INTEGER, T2ID INTEGER)


INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES ('Adam')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES ('Mark')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES ('David')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES ('Jeremy')

INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES ('Jessica')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES ('Jeremy')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES ('David')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES ('Mark')

INSERT INTO @Table3 VALUES (2, 4)
INSERT INTO @Table3 VALUES (3, 3)
INSERT INTO @Table3 VALUES (4, 2)
```

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID), t1.Value
FROM    @Table1 t1
UNION ALL 
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) + offset, t2.Value
FROM    @Table2 t2
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @Table3 t3 ON t3.T2ID = t2.ID
        CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT  Offset = COUNT(*)
          FROM    @Table1
        ) offset
WHERE   t3.T2ID IS NULL
```

Comment: @chacham15, not the most elegant solution but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have below data, as I understand reading your question:

```
Table: T1
ID  name
--------
1   a
2   b
3   c

Table: T2
ID  name
--------
2   b
3   c
4   d

Table: Rel
ID1  ID2
--------
2   2
3   3
```

T1 has some data which is not in T2 and vice versa.
Following query will give all data unioned

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by name) ID, Col
from 
(
SELECT ISNULL(T1.name,'') name
FROM T1 t1 LEFT JOIN Rel TR ON TR.ID1 = T1.ID
union
SELECT ISNULL(T2.name,'') name
FROM T2 t2 LEFT JOIN Rel TR ON TR.ID2 = T2.ID
) T
```

Comment: problem is that the result must also have an id field

Comment: @chacham15: In that case the ID from which table you want in result? or you want both?

Comment: This wont work if there exists rows which were deleted from t1

Comment: @chacham, true but how were we supposed to know? You keep changing the requirements and leave to much open for speculation.

Comment: @chacham15: In this way, it is not possible for anybody to solve the problem in your mind. Try to jot it down on paper before you finalize the question.

Comment: i didnt realize how ambiguous it was, therefore the question has been changed to clarify